# YUI Image Rotator / YUI3-Slideshow Link Issue

Tags: javascript, yui, slideshow, yui3

First off, I CANNOT use jQuery. Don't suggest that!

I'm having trouble with the YUI standard image slideshow. I can get it to work perfectly without links, but not WITH links. I need to use this as a advertising banner platform and no links really renders this useless.

Without links: http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/U6q2K/

With links (itll start red! fade! but then come back red....): http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/ef2QV/

No anchor tags here for some reason? Why would this break? It really doesn't make sense to me.

I'm new to YUI -- if this is just a bug that can't be fixed, how would I go about faking links here -- adding a onclick class that work work for the different images?

Thanks for any help --

Answer (score 0):

OK -- this always seems to happen to me when I post on SO. I struggle for 3 hours, then I post and I figure it out.

So all the style was completely unnecessary and managed through YUI -- oops

```
style="visibility: hidden; z-index: -30000; opacity: 0;
```

this now works with links! -- http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/bn3TL/